# What is the best way to code a decision tree? (conditional rendering/visibility/others)

Tags: flutter, dart

I am coding an app in flutter that follows a decision tree to determine what insect a person has found. What is thhe best way to go about this. The image at the bottom shows a simple example of the kind of tree I'm trying to follow.

When the user answers the first question, I'd like to show the next question below, which will vary based on user input. For reference, I may have some questions that aren't a simple yes/no answer, but break into three paths (i.e. 6 legs/8 legs/many legs)

I'm not sure how this is possible in flutter, as when I put an if statement into the scaffold like this:.

`if (input == "yes") {show widget1}`

`else if (input == "no") {render widget2}`

"The element type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'"

I think what I am trying to do involves contditional rendering, and have seen that this may be possible with the "visibility" class, but it still doesn't seem like the best solution. I would appreciate any suggestions or example code.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if your possible entries are binary (only two options) you could use the ternary like this:

```
input=='yes'?show widget1:show widget2;
```

Just to you know: ternary executes the code following ? if the previous condition is true, and else it executes the code after :

In case you need to render and take non-binary decisions, you could create a map method or use `if(condition) show widget` (note that I didn't use curly braces)